# How to convert last month first day to Y-m-d format in php

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get first day of last month in Y-m-d formats ,

but its not working.

below is my code.

```html
<?php  
  $old_date= date('M Y 1', strtotime('-1 months'));//Aug 2017 1

  $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
  $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $old_date_timestamp); ///I want In "2017-08-01"

?>
```

Comment: Well, I mean you could just do `date('Y-m-01', $old_date_timestamp)`.

Comment: yes got it thank  you.

Comment: `$x = new DateTime('first day of last month');
echo $x->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this:

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('-1 months'));   


//should return 2017-08-01
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php